# How to run Zend Studio Remote Systems SSH using sudo bash

Tags: bash, zend-framework, ssh, sudo, zend-studio

In regular SSH, I can login as a user "foobar" with a password "pwd" and type sudo bash and the same password "pwd" to perform superuser activities.

I setup a Zend Studio WorkSpace for the same SSH server using Remote Systems SSH access and login as user "foobar" with password "pwd".

How can I then access the project tree?  The error I get is: "Operation failed. Security Violation".  How can I sudo bash in Zend Studio using the password "pwd" to be able to browse the svn repository tree just like I would if I logged in as "root" and its password "thepwd"?

Answer (score 0):

change the permission of that directory and it's children to make it available to user foobar

```
sudo chmod u+rwx -R <directory>
```